# What eats small holes in mint?

Tags: mint

I put some chicken coop compost around my mint patch this year, and there seems to be small holes being eaten in the mint leaves. What would cause this?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because there isnt enough information.  At the very least a phot should have been provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How big are the holes? Some photos would be useful!

Mint is pretty pest-resistant. Usually, small, uneven holes are from flea beetles, but I've never seen them eat mint, even when nearby plants were infested.

If the holes are larger and circular, like up to a half a centimetre (3/16th of an inch), it could be leaf-cutter bees. They don't eat the mint; they use leaf circles in their dwelling.

Comment: it's leaving droppings on the ledge behind.

Comment: That's odd. Mint is very pest-resistant. Some photos of the leaf damage may be useful.